# Without internet connection, how xmlns attribute can work and understand by browser?

Tags: html, xhtml, xml-namespaces, internet-connection

A simple XHTML document, with the minimum of required tags: and **xmlns** attribute has a http link.

If I am working on localhost and if I don't have an Internet connection, can't I work on XHTML?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        The content of the document......
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The XML namespace is just there to identify elements based on a namespace, which *happens to be* in a URI format. See the [XML Namespaces spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names). In this case, `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` is the namespace for XHTML; an XML processor will be able to use this information to identify which elements are in the XHTML namespace (identified by that URL).

The browser isn't going to attempt to request the URL that's listed in the `xmlns` attribute. Even if it does, it won't receive anything useful anyway; visit http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml in your browser and see for yourself.

So there's nothing to worry about, even if you're working on a development machine with no Internet connection. You'll still be able to write valid XHTML.

Comment: Does that mean the XML processor has the namespace and its elements (xsd file) cached?

Comment: @Kentative: No, the namespace doesn't contain the schema. The schema is found elsewhere and never used by an XML processor - only by a validator.