# What is the significance of xmlns="http://schemas..."? Does it require Internet access?

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces, schema, xml-namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Without internet connection, how xmlns attribute can work and understand by browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539253/without-internet-connection-how-xmlns-attribute-can-work-and-understand-by-brow)

Does using `xmlns="http://schemas..."` instead of `xmlns="clr-namespace:..."` mean you need **internet access** to reference the resource ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. See the post quoted in the comment for an explanation of xmlns. In addition to that: if you have a .Net component and want to make it available to XAML using this namespace syntax, you can do so by setting this attribute where you define the namespace:

```
<Assembly: System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/commanding", "WPFGlue.Commanding")> 
<Assembly: System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsPrefix("http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/commanding", "c")> 

Namespace Commanding
    ...
```